# How login by remote desktop using the disabled admin account?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, user-accounts

I disabled the the local admin account on my vps by mistake and it was the only active account on it, and now I can't access to my server by remote desktop connection.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does your VPS host give you any other access to the machine, via say, VNC or some other console emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You need console access to boot in to safe mode, wich many VPS providers have via control panels etc.

Call your VPS provider.